# Como mudar a Cor do Texto de um listView?

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando mudar a cor do TEXTO desse listView que eu fiz seguindo alguns exemplos na internet, mas o máximo que eu consegui foi o comentário da *linha 39** ***txt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);*** O problema é que isso só altera a cor quando clicado e mesmo assim a cor nem volta ao normal. :/ Preciso de uma solução para deixar a aparência uma pouco mais bonita, Ja tentei vários tutorias de outros site mais não deram muito certo.

Gostaria de uma solução que fosse o mais simples possível para estudos. Mas qualquer coisa que funcione vale também. :)

**A classe Main:**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    public ListView list;
    static int numPerildo = 2;
    static String perildoAtual;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cursos);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView txt = (TextView) view;     //funciona
                //txt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                //TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post);

                //mensagem.setTitle("Escolha qual o perildo");
                //mensagem.setMessage( txt.getText().toString() );
                //mensagem.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                //txt.setTextColor(color.white);

                //trace("Item selecionado : " + position);

                if(txt.getText().toString().equals("valor 1")){
                    numPerildo = 5;
                    telaPerildo();
                }

                perildoAtual = txt.getText().toString();
            }
        });

    }

    public void telaPerildo(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Periodo.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    static final String[] Cursos = new String[] {"valor 1", 
        "valor 2", 
        "valor 3"};


    public void toast (String msg){
        Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    } 

    private void trace (String msg){
        toast (msg);
    }

}
```

**A Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/azulClaro"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Escolha o seu curso:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você quer mudar a cor de todos os items do `ListView`.

Como você esta usando o `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, que é fornecido pelo Android e esta usando um `ArrayAdapter`, não é possível alterar a cor com essa configuração.

Alterar a cor do texto no método `onItemClick` do `OnItemClickListener` de fato só irá alterar durante o click e não irá voltar ao normal.

Há duas opções:

Usar um layout customizado, semelhante ao `simple_list_item_1` com a modificação no `TextView`, assim como abaixo:

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/suaCor"
/>
```

É preciso respeitar o `id` que é atribuído ao `TextView` para que o `ArrayAdapter` saiba localizar o `TextView`.

E usar em sua `Activity` desse modo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, Cursos);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Restante do código...
}
```

A segunda opção é extender o `ArrayAdapter` para modificar a cor ao instânciar o item. Dessa forma:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cursos) {

        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            // Como o simple_list_item_1 retorna um TextView, esse cast pode ser feito sem problemas
            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(suaCor);

            return view;
        }

    };

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Restante do código...
}
```

As duas alternativas são possíveis, a primeira é mais "correta", porque você altera diretamente no layout do item e também da mais possibilidades de customização e é mais performática que a segunda.

A segunda é um pouco forçada (usando classes anônimas), porque sobrecarrega o comportamento do Adapter, da pra fazer muita coisa dessa forma em termos de lógica de visibilidade e etc (pode-se criar sua própria classe que extende o ArrayAdapter em um arquivo separado, fica mais organizado).

Resumindo, para esse caso simples eu recomendo a primeira hehe

Comment: Huumm, Agora sim esta fazendo sentido, Muito obrigado @Wakim ! Eu preferir a segunda opção e funcionou Perfeitamente, Voce entendeu o que eu quis dizer!

Comment: Coloquei algumas considerações para ajudar.

Comment: Dannark segue as considerações do @Walkim (1ªopção) que mais tarde ou mais cedo vai te dar jeito saberes criar o teu próprio adaptador, para que possas usar os teus objetos no adaptador. É aproveitar os recursos dos objetos Java e do XML do Android.

Comment: Valeu pessoal :)

Answer (score 3):

Tens de criar um *layout* costumizado par a `ListView`, e depois usar esse *layout* no adaptador.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lisItem"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Podes me mostrar como fazer isso? Obrigado pela rapida resposta!

Comment: Vê a resposta do @Walkim