# Como personalizar a linha de uma ListVIew de acordo com o valor no ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, array, xml, listview

Supondo que eu tenha um objeto chamado Item, e que nele possua as propriedade texto, id e validação, no caso, texto é uma string, id é um inteiro, e validação é um valor booleano.

```
class Item
{
    private int id;
    private String texto;
    private boolean validacao;
    //get and set
}
```

E que este objeto sirva como parâmetro para um ArrayAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter<Item> itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item(this,R.layout.layoutItem,view)
//no momento os parametros do construtor do ArrayAdapter não são levados em conta
```

Porém preciso ter a possibilidade de personalizar alguns elementos de cada linha do  ListView de acordo com o items.

Cada linha terá:

1- uma imagem, que será escolhida de acordo com o valor do atributo validação do Item da linha atual.

2- um EditText, que receberá e manipulará o valor da propriedade texto do Item da linha atual.

4- uma imagem com o desenho de uma lixeira que ao ser clicada exclui o item atual.

5- O id  do item deve ser alterado conforme a posição na array.

Como posso personalizar as linhas da view desta maneira?, devo criar uma classe que estende a classe ArrayAdapter ?, tem alguns exemplos ?, ou uma alternativa, ou padrão, melhor para esta necessidade ?

Comment: Isso mesmo Leonardo, você terá que extender a classe `ArrayAdapter`. Segue um exemplo de uma pergunta que respondi, pode te ajudar a começar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26229/como-mudar-a-cor-do-texto-de-um-listview/26231#26231. No caso você pode alterar elementos de uma linha, adicionar `Listeners`.

Comment: seria essa uma maneira certa ? http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: porém ainda resta uma duvida ainda , os eventos de um elemento dentro de uma lista iram responder normalmente como por exemplo , on click listener

Comment: Exatamente, meu exemplo era só para pintar a cor do texto, mas é possível fazer muito mais coisa. Sim, eles vão responder normalmente, bastando adicionar o listener. Para isso sugiro (não é obrigatório) usar esse modo que fiz na resposta a essa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32771/problemas-ao-enviar-dados-de-um-listview-para-outra-activity/32885#32885. Usando o `Adapter` como o `OnClickListener` você evita de criar tantos `Listeners` quantos forem os itens do seu `ListView`, melhor para o GC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou mostrar um exemplo usando com Adapter customizado usando TextView e um Button, resultando na imagem abaixo e que deseja inserir 50 elementos por exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Classe MainActitvy que tem base um ListView:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private NumeroAdapter adapter;
    private final int numero = 50;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        adapter = new NumeroAdapter(this, numero);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Classe NumeroAdapter que utliza o BaseAdapter customizado responsável por mostrar na tela:

```
public class NumeroAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    private List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;


    public NumeroAdapter(Context context, int tamanho) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            array.add(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return array.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.texto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.texto);
            holder.info = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.info);
            holder.info.setOnClickListener(this);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.texto.setText(array.get(position));
        holder.info.setTag(array.get(position));
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(context, (String) v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Interface ViewHolder responsável por gerenciar as views que são mostradas na tela:

```
public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView texto;
    public Button info;
}
```

Layout utilizado pelo adapter:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/info"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/info" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/info" />
```

Esse exemplo serve de apoio para que você seja capaz de solucionar seu problema.