# Mudar cor e estilo da fonte do Listview nao funciona

Tags: android

Olá, ainda sou um bebe em programação, não posso negar que tenho avançado e vcs tem ajudado, vejam bem eu tenho um listview com busca, que a lista vem de um string array, o codigo em si funciona perfeito, mas eu estou tentando mudar a cor do texto e a fonte para negrito, da lista, e pois bem consigo fazer isso com o codigo abaixo, mas no meu onclick eu tenho um "if" para cada texto clicado, uns 8 textos, e ai esta o problema o onclick não funciona quando mudo a cor e fonte do texto, quando não há estas alterações funciona tudo normal. Desde jã obrigado a todos.
A partegunta acima onde diz que possivelmente é duplicada tem um codigo completamente difetente!
Segue parte do meu codigo:

```
lvbr = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvsbr);
etbr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etsr);

lst = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sonsbr);


lvbr.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.seila, R.id.txtcor, lst));
    CarregarEncontrados();

lvbr.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(cardiobrasil.this, R.layout.seila, R.id.txtcor, lst_Encontrados));

        }
    });


lvbr.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {



            if (((TextView) view).getText().equals("Salto")) {
                setContentView(R.layout.brc01);
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como mudar a Cor do Texto de um listView?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26229/como-mudar-a-cor-do-texto-de-um-listview)

Comment: Obrigado, o assunto acima realmente é parecido, mas eu nao uso uma classe pro adapter eu fiz ai mesmo na propia classe da activity, beleza eu consigo mudar a cor do texto dos itens da lista e o tipo de fonte, mas como disse eu tenho um if no onclick para cada texto clicado, dai quando a lista esta com a cor e a fonte mudada ele nao vai pra onde deveria, ou melhor simplesmente nao funciona. sacou?

Answer (score 0):

No link que o Júnior Moreira enviou, contém a resposta para sua pergunta. Se você olhar mais abaixo na resposta, ele dá o exemplo utilizando classe anônima.

Segue o trecho do código modificado para sua necessidade:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.seila, lst_Encontrados) {

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // teste aqui se o view é referente ao seu textview do layout
        if (view == parent.findViewById(R.id.seutextview) {
            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(cor); // substitua 'cor' pela cor desejada
            ((TextView) view).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }

        return view;
    }

};

lvbr.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Questão similar: [Como mudar a Cor do Texto de um listView?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26229/como-mudar-a-cor-do-texto-de-um-listview)